# When I use one instead of a/an?

Tags: word-usage

I'm study English today and I have a question about the sentence

```
I have one attempt
```

Is it correct to say?

```
I have an attempt
```

However, when I use **one** or **a/an**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words, '**a**' and '**an**', are **connectives** used in the same area roughly.

- '**a**' - This is used as a **connective** when the following word does NOT begin with a vowel. Vowels are... A, E, I, O, U. A correct sentence containing 'a' would be...

  > "... I was running across the street till **a** car hit me."
- '**an**' - This is also used as a **connective** when the following word is a **noun** that begins with a vowel. Words that you would use '**an**' behind include;

  > apple, energy, eggs
  >
  > > An example in a sentence would be; "... I need to call **an** ambulance."

'**One**' is different, as it is used not as a **connective** but as a **pronoun**. '**One'** is an easy way to **refer to a person or a thing** that was **previously mentioned or easily identified**. An example would be...;

> "... That is the **one** evil of our country," answered the invisible man"

Regarding your question, your first sentence is **information** - you are telling someone they only have one attempt. You are using '**one**' as a **number**, not as a **pronoun**. The second sentence also clarifies you only have one attempt, however it is worded **quite awkwardly**. Try phrasing it like so;

> "I have **an attempt** to study"
>
> > Try to make sure to describe what you're doing to make more sense in the sentence, similar to other languages.